# How to add custom JS file?

Tags: module, magento2.3, javascript

I have created a custom module for Megamenu. I have js file which needs to be added to this module.

Some of my queries are:

- Can I add the js file directly on my module?. If yes, how to do it?
- Do I need to add it on theme? If that's right, how to do it?

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can add the js file directly on your module. 
Follow the steps below

1.Add your js file in the path

> app/code/Companyname/Modulename/view/frontend/web/js/script.js

2. Create requirejs_config.js at the below locations

> app/code/Companyname/Modulename/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

3. In the above file specify the script.js

```
var config = {
    map: {
        "*": {
            "somename": "Companyname_Modulename/js/script",
        }
    },

};
```

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1** : Move your file in `VENDOR/EXTENSION/view/frontend/web/js/some_name.js`

**Step 2** : Add your file in layout like `module_index_index.xml`

```
<head>
    <script src="VENDOR_EXTENSION::js/some_name.js"/>
</head>
```

**Step 3** : Execute Command `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

Then give permission if required.

Now, after refreshing the page and check in the view source you will get this file.

Thanks

Comment: We have to create manually the file module_index_index.xml, am i right?

Comment: Yes and if there in your custom extension then you can directly code in it. @Siva